# AWS S3 bucket via HTTP POST request from JS/React FE web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3, httprequest, image-uploading

Does anyone have specific instructions for making an HTTP POST request from a Javascript or React app to upload an image directly to an AWS s3 bucket?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to illustrate your specific problem.

Comment: I contacted aws support directly and they were able to offer alternatives that worked.